# Image Rotation on above header background with size responsive in multi divice

Tags: html, css, rotation, responsive

I tried this code for header, a girl image in bg and the knowledges in small images should rotating from one hand to another hand,

I'm expecting this effect to be responsive view on multi device compatibility.

Also if the small images only visible above hands so that rotations looks half rounded path it will helpful to me.

```css
    body {
    padding: 2em;
    margin-top: 5em;
    }

    #container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
    }

    .item {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #;
    animation: spin 10s linear infinite reverse;
    }
    @keyframes spin {
    100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
    }
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwkdk.jpg); width:100%">
    <div >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbkaT.png" width="130" height="130"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWcXb.png" width="130" height="130"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4xAd.png" width="130" height="130"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YEcj.png" width="130" height="130"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YEcj.png" width="130" height="130"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YEcj.png" width="130" height="130"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YEcj.png" width="130" height="130" ></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var radius = 320; // adjust to move out items in and out 
    var fields = $('.item'),
    container = $('#container'),
    width = container.width(),
    height = container.height();
    var angle = 0,
    step = (2 * Math.PI) / fields.length;
    fields.each(function() {
    var x = Math.round(width / 2 + radius * Math.cos(angle) - $(this).width() / 2);
    var y = Math.round(height / 2 + radius * Math.sin(angle) - $(this).height() / 2);
    if (window.console) {
    console.log($(this).text(), x, y);
    }
    $(this).css({
    left: x + 'px',
    top: y + 'px'
    });
    angle += step;
    });
    </script>
              
    </div>
    </div>
```